# Why is 'init' not assignable?

Tags: swift

I just read that the `init` method can't be used as a value. Meaning:

```
var x = SomeClass.someClassFunction // ok
var y = SomeClass.init              // error
```

Example found on [Language reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/primary-expression)

Why should it be like that? Is it a way to enforce language level that *too dirty tricks* come into place, because of some cohertion or maybe because it interferes with another feature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike Obj-C, where the `init` function can be called multiple times without problems, in Swift there actually is no method called `init`.

`init` is just a keyword meaning "the following is a constructor". The constructor is called always via `MyClass()` during the creation of a new instance. It's never called separately as a method `myInstance.init()`. You can't get a reference to the underlying function because it would be impossible to call it.

This is also connected with the fact that constructors cannot be inherited. Code

```
var y = SomeClass.init
```

would also break subtyping because the subtypes are not required to have the same initializers.

Answer (score 0):

> Why should it be like that?

`init` is a special member, not a regular method.

Beyond that, there's no reason that you'd ever need to store `init` in a variable. The only objects that could use that function in a valid way are instances of the class where that particular `init` is defined, and any such object will have already been initialized before you could possibly make the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Initializers don't have a return value. In order to assign it to something, it should be able to return something - and it doesn't.